# How do you use your struct variable from a file in an arithmetic operation?

Tags: c, math, file-handling

I have this project, an ATM account system using files and structure in c.
now I have almost every function down, except my deposit/withdrawal function.
If I’m not mistaken, you just have to read the file and call the variable you want to use in an arithmetic operation then write it back to the file to update it.

It works fine if the user inputs a new value for said variable (but I can't have that cuz then the user can change his/her account balance at will).

But when I do just that it doesn't work.

in short, my problem is that my transaction (user enters an amount to deposit and the system adds that amount to the user's account balance that is saved inside a binary file, then the system gets the sum of these 2 for the new account balance then overwrites the old account balance) doesn't work specifically, my struct and user input variable are not adding up

Here’s my function

```
void deposit()
{
   system("cls");
   FILE *fp,*fp1;
   struct acc rec,rec1;
   int id,pinc,found=0,count=0;
   float dv=0,wv=0;
   fp=fopen(fname,"rb");
   fp1=fopen("tempacc.dat","wb");

   printf("\nEnter Account No :");
   scanf("%d",&id);
   printf("\nEnter PIN :");
   scanf("%d",&pinc);

   while(1)
   {
     fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

   if(feof(fp))
   {
      break;
   }
   if(rec.no==id && rec.pin==pinc)
   {
     found=1;
     printf("current balance:%0.2f",&rec.id);
     printf("\nEnter initial deposit:");
     scanf("%d",&rec.id);
     printf("\nEnter Deposit value:");
     scanf("%f",dv);
     rec.id = rec.id + dv; <--- (this part doesn't work)
     printf("\nNew Account Balance:%f",rec.id);
     fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);
   }
    else
   {
    fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);
   }
   }
   fclose(fp);
   fclose(fp1);

   if(found==0)
   {
    printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
   }
   else
   {
    fp=fopen(fname,"wb");
    fp1=fopen("tempacc.dat","rb");

   while(1)
   {
     fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);

   if(feof(fp1))
   {
      break;
   }
   fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);
  }

}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
}
```

my main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct acc
{
    int no;
    char name[100];
    int pin;
    float id;
}; 

void append();
void display();
void displayAll();
void modify();
void search();
void deposit();

char mygetch();

char fname[]={"accdb.dat"};

int main()
{
char ch;

while(1)
{
system("cls"); //clrscr();

printf("==================Welcome to Banking System=============\n\n");

printf("A. Open an Account \n\n");
printf("B. Bank transaction \n\n");
printf("C. Exit\n\n");
//printf("D. Display\n\n");
//printf("E. Display All\n\n");
//printf("F. Search\n\n");

printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("\nPlease enter your Choice:");
scanf("%c",&ch);

switch(ch)
{
case 'A': append();
break;

case 'B': modify();
break;

case 'C': exit(0);

case 'D': display();
break;

case 'E': displayAll();
break;

case 'F':   search();
break;

}

mygetch();
}

return 0;
}
void append()
{
system("cls");
FILE *fp;
struct acc rec;

fp=fopen(fname,"ab");

printf("\nEnter Account no:");
scanf("%d",&rec.no);
getchar();
printf("\nEnter Account name:");
scanf("%[^\n]s",rec.name);
printf("\nEnter PIN:");
scanf("%d",&rec.pin);
printf("\nEnter Initial Deposit:");
scanf("%f",&rec.id);
fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

fclose(fp);
}

void display()
{
system("cls");
FILE *fp;
struct acc rec;
int id,found=0;

fp=fopen(fname,"rb");

printf("\nEnter the account number:");
scanf("%d",&id);

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
if(rec.no==id)
{
found=1;
printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
printf("\t\t Account Details of %d\n\n",rec.no);
printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("Name\tBalance\n\n");

printf("%s\t",rec.name);
printf("%0.2f\t\n\n",rec.id);

printf("========================================================\n\n");
}
}
if(found==0)
{
printf("\nSorry No Record Found");
}
fclose(fp);

}

void deposit()
{
system("cls");
FILE *fp,*fp1;
struct acc rec,rec1;
int id,pinc,found=0,count=0;
float dv=0,wv=0;
fp=fopen(fname,"rb");
fp1=fopen("tempacc.dat","wb");

printf("\nEnter Account No :");
scanf("%d",&id);
printf("\nEnter PIN :");
scanf("%d",&pinc);

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
if(rec.no==id && rec.pin==pinc)
{
found=1;
printf("current balance:%0.2f",&rec.id);
printf("\nEnter initial deposit:");
scanf("%d",&rec.id);
printf("\nEnter Deposit value:");
scanf("%f",dv);
rec.id = rec.id + dv;
//scanf("%f",&rec.id);
printf("\nNew Account Balance:%f",rec.id);
//scanf("%f",&rec.id);
fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);
//fflush(stdin);


}
else
{
fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);
}
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);

if(found==0)
{
printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
}
else
{
fp=fopen(fname,"wb");
fp1=fopen("tempacc.dat","rb");

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp1);

if(feof(fp1))
{
break;
}
fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);
}

}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
}

void search()
{
FILE *fp;
struct acc rec;
int found=0;
char name[20];

fp=fopen(fname,"rb");

printf("\nEnter the Account Name:");
scanf("%s",&name);

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
if(strcmp(name,rec.name)==0)
{
printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
printf("\t\t Account Details of %d\n\n",rec.no);
printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("Name\tbalance\n\n");

printf("%s\t",rec.name);
printf("%0.2f\t\n\n",rec.id);

printf("========================================================\n\n");

}
}
if(found==0)
{
printf("\nSorry No Record Found");
}
fclose(fp);
}

void displayAll()
{
system("cls");
FILE *fp;
struct acc rec;

fp=fopen(fname,"rb");

printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
printf("\t\t All Account Details\n\n");
printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("ID\tName\tPIN\tBalance\n\n");

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
printf("%d\t",rec.no);
printf("%s\t",rec.name);
printf("%d\t",rec.pin);
printf("%0.2f\t\n\n",rec.id);


}
printf("========================================================\n\n");

fclose(fp);
}

char mygetch()
{
char val;
char rel;

scanf("%c",&val);
scanf("%c",&rel);
return (val);
}

void modify()
{
system("cls");
FILE *fp,*fp1;
struct acc rec,rec1;
int id,pinc,found=0,count=0;

fp=fopen(fname,"rb");
fp1=fopen("tempacc.dat","wb");

printf("\nEnter Account No:");
scanf("%d",&id);
printf("\nEnter PIN:");
scanf("%d",&pinc);

while(1)
{
fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,fp);

if(feof(fp))
{
break;
}
if(rec.no==id && rec.pin==pinc)
{
found=1;
int sch;

printf("\tWelcome to Banking System\n");
            printf("1.Balance Inquiry\n");
            printf("2.Deposit\n");
            printf("3.Withdrawal\n");
            printf("4.quit\n");
scanf("%d",&sch);

switch (sch)
{
    case 1:
        display();
        break;
    case 2:
        fclose(fp);
        deposit();
        break;
    case 3:
        //withdrawal();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Thank you for your patronage\n");
        exit(0);
        break;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? That usually helps to explain what is wrong. What is `struct acc`? This looks wrong too, did you notice the current balance was already incorrect? `printf("current balance:%0.2f",&rec.id);`

Comment: Lacking indentation, the code is completely unreadable. Further, your description isn’t sufficient to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @RaymondChen no error messages that's why i asked here.

Comment: You need to be more specific what you mean by "It just doesn't work." Since the code compiles, you can use a debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: @RaymondChen  noted.

Comment: Please read about how to make a [mcve]. Your code is neither minimal nor complete.

Comment: Again, you need to be more specific what you mean by "It just doesn't work." I think that if you look at the value of `rec.id` in the debugger immediately before the offending line, and add it to the value in `dv` on a pocket calculator, then the result will match the value of `rec.id` after the offending line. So the `rec.id = rec.id  dv;` "worked" in the sense that it did exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking more details, I would *guess* that your `scanf` combination is in effect reading for `%d%f`, i.e. a decimal number immediately followed by a floating-point number. If that's the case, it *should* work, in a way: If you enter `123.456` it should take initial deposit `123` and new deposit `0.456`.

But I guess you meant for users to enter two distinct numbers, with enter between them. If so, your input will be first number then newline then second number. You need to parse that as `%d %f` (since space matches any number of whitespace, including newlines). If you don't want the first `scanf` to wait till the first non-space after the first number, I suggest you include the space with the second `scanf` i.e. make that scan `" %f"`.

If all of this is wrong, chances are that still something is wrong with your `scanf` so you should do error checking for that. Read the manual, see what it should return for valid input, then have your code complain if that's not what it's getting.